# system.web functionality in Mono missing?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, system.web, html-escape-characters

I need HttpUtility for encoding strings, but it seems it was supported, but no longer.
Actually, the whole System.Web is gone.

Is there an alternative? I need to Javascript Escape some strings.

Comment: What kind of project are you working on? an asp.net site?

Comment: System.Web is not gone in Mono.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The HttpUtility class lives in the System.Web.Services assembly, just make sure that you are referencing that assembly.

Comment: Its a bit confusing that I can just see System.Web.Services in the references, but not System.Web. But adding Services gives me Web too. thanks.

Comment: To clarify - HttpUtility is inside System.Web.dll in the desktop/server framework. However, since MonoTouch doesn't include ASP.NET, HttpUtility was moved to System.Web.Services.dll.

Comment: To further clarify, the namespace is still the same although it's in the different `.dll`, i.e. you still need `using System.Web` and _not_ `using System.Web.Services`.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Xamarin Studio with Mono 3.0.10 and in there, you need to reference the System.Web dll and include it with

```
using System.Web;
```

Then you will have the HTTPUtility and encode/decode functionality available